# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing scip: No module found

Tags: python, pyscipopt

I'm trying test example:

```
from pyscipopt import Model
model = Model("Example")  # model name is optional
x = model.addVar("x")
y = model.addVar("y", vtype="INTEGER")
model.setObjective(x + y)
model.addCons(2*x - y*y >= 0)
model.optimize()
sol = model.getBestSol()
print("x: {}".format(sol[x]))
print("y: {}".format(sol[y]))
```

but got

```
runfile('C:/Users/man_c/Downloads/ProHeatNet_Sim-master without Gurobi/ProHeatNet_Sim-master/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/man_c/Downloads/ProHeatNet_Sim-master without Gurobi/ProHeatNet_Sim-master')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\man_c\Downloads\ProHeatNet_Sim-master without Gurobi\ProHeatNet_Sim-master\untitled0.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model

  File "C:\Users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyscipopt\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing scip: No module found.
```

Have tried everything listed here: https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set SCIPOPTDIR=C:\SCIPOptSuite 8.0.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install pyscipopt
Collecting pyscipopt
  Using cached PySCIPOpt-4.2.0.tar.gz (661 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyscipopt) (0.37.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
  Building wheel for pyscipopt (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pyscipopt: filename=PySCIPOpt-4.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl size=612019 sha256=a931e29e41d971e957d4ed3397b244ed4c3b6321512870493572c1c7f0a0bdd5
  Stored in directory: c:\users\man_c\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\15\c8\80\0b7bc0e370527c3241b54ee3949698f0a06c5697eae6b60038
Successfully built pyscipopt
Installing collected packages: pyscipopt
Successfully installed pyscipopt-4.2.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pytest
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (6.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (21.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12 in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.8.2 in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: atomicwrites>=1.0 in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (3.0.4)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install pyscipopt
Requirement already satisfied: pyscipopt in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (4.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\man_c\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyscipopt) (0.37.0)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- --------------------
...
PySCIPOpt                          4.2.0
```

Got the same issue as described here: https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/issues/467 by mariaeileen, but no solution available. The only difference is error itself:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyscipopt'`
```

Is that important?
While installing saw this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbIHW.png)
but did this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%SCIPOPTDIR%\bin
```

Was that enough?